# C^2 regularity of a family of solutions to elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following question, I apologize in advance if it looks classical, but I've not found any precise reference pointing to the solution so far. I have the solutions $u_s$ ($s>0$) to the family of elliptic equations $-\Delta u=f_s$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$, where $f_s$ are assumed to be smooth, with (say) zero Dirichlet boundary condition. Can I derive somehow the C^{2} regularity of the map $s\in (0,+\infty)\rightarrow u_s\in X$, where $X$ is some functional space? I found this result cited in a paper, but no reference to such a result was given.

Thank you very much,
Bruno

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting here and at MO. A question can be migrated by a moderator if you ask them (via a flag). Not getting an answer within 8 hours is not a reason to conclude that the question is abandoned... If you do crosspost, make sure  both questions have a link to the other version: http://mathoverflow.net/q/168770

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the solution operator is continuous from (whatever space $f_s$ live in) to $X$.

Let's say $f_s$ belong to some function space $Y$. Assume $s\to f_s$ is   $C^2$ smooth, in the sense that
$$f_{s+h} = f_s+hp_s+h^2q_s+o(h^2)\tag1 $$
where $f_s$, $p_s$, $q_s$ are all norm-continuous with respect to $s$, and $o$ is with respect to the norm in $Y$. The Poisson equation is linear, and its solution is given by the convolution with Green's function $G$. Therefore, we    convolve (1) with $G$ to obtain 
$$  u_{s+h}  = G*f_{s+h} = u_s+h G*p_s+h^2 G*q_s+G*o(h^2)
\tag2 $$
 By assumption, convolution with $G$ is continuous from $Y$ to $X$. Hence, 
$$  u_{s+h}  =   u_s+h P_s+h^2 Q_s+ o(h^2)
\tag3 $$
where $P_s$ and $Q_s$ are norm-continuous functions into $X$, and $o$ is with respect to the norm in $X$.

Comment: I liked your coincise argument, it seems it can be applied to a great variety of operators. Thank you very much!